# zone.js cannot be resolved

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, zone.js

After upgrading to the latest Angular `cli`, when I run `ng serve`, I get the following error:

`./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/es5-polyfills.js:106:0-37 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zone.js/plugins/zone-legacy' in 'C:\Users\Reem\App\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack'`

I have tried every solution and suggestion in the posts that exist about `zone.js` related issues and errors, but nothing has resolved it...

Does anyone know how to fix this in the latest Angular version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing latest package of angular in your project.
You can try below.
Delete current node module folder.
Delete package lock file.
Install npm install @angular/cli and then npm install.
Try ng serve again.